# Cannot create property on string angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm getting form from api request, some of this fields based on ng-options. The data for options comes from angular services. So on the page it looks like: 
 after form has been opened:

1. depends on key, fields can be:

   - disabled for modifications
   - enabled for modifications
2. enabled for modifications fields can be:

   - with simple input
   - with options

For now everything is good, form has been opened and rendered. Now if I want to modify something, simple input fields can be modified without any problem, and can be changed in db, but if I want to modified options fields, I'm getting this errors:

for priority:

> Cannot create property 'priorityId' on string 'priority'

for severity:

> Cannot create property 'severityId' on string 'severity'

for status:

> Cannot create property 'statusId' on string 'status'

Where is my mistake? this is [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SccT3wcDIwgN7ymLeDwB?p=preview)

my services

```
    (function () {

    angular.module("app").factory("eventService", ["$http", "$q", "$log",
        function ($http, $q, $log) {

            var severityOptionsFunc = [
                {
                    name: "Benign",
                    id: 4,
                    labelStyle: "label-danger"
                },
                {
                    name: "Severe",
                    id: 3,
                    labelStyle: "label-warning"
                },
                {
                    name: "Medium",
                    id: 2,
                    labelStyle: "label-info"
                },
                {
                    name: "Mild",
                    id: 1,
                    labelStyle: "label-success"
                }
            ];
            var  priorityOptionsFunc = [
                {
                    name: "High",
                    id: 3,
                    labelStyle: "label-warning"
                },
                {
                    name: "Medium",
                    id: 2,
                    labelStyle: "label-info"
                },
                {
                    name: "Low",
                    id: 1,
                    labelStyle: "label-success"
                }
            ];
            var  statusOptionsFunc = [
                {
                    name: "Open",
                    id: 1,
                    labelStyle: "label-info"
                },
                {
                    name: "Closed",
                    id: 5,
                    labelStyle: "label-success"
                }
            ];



            var statusOptions = function () {
                return statusOptionsFunc;
        };
        var priorityOptions = function () {
                return priorityOptionsFunc;
        };
        var severityOptions = function () {
                return severityOptionsFunc;
        };


        var findById = function (id, list) {
            var i=0, len=list.length;
            for (; i<len; i++) {
              if (list[i].id == id) {
                 return list[i];
              }
            }
            return {};
    };

        var toName = function (id, list) {
            var i=0, len=list.length;
            for (; i<len; i++) {
              if (list[i].id == id) {
                 return list[i].name;
              }
            }
        return id
    };
        return {
            statusOptions: statusOptions,
            priorityOptions: priorityOptions,
            severityOptions: severityOptions,


            toName: toName,
            findById: findById
        };
    }]);

}());
```

html

```
     <div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!0' | filter: '!$$'" ng-model="rowVal" >
<div ng-if="(k === 'id' || k.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">

    <label for="rowValue[{{$index}}]" class="col-sm-2">

        {{k | hide:'.name' | makeUppercase }}:
    </label>
    <div class=" col-sm-2">
        <input ng-if="!isObject(rowData[k])"
               ng-disabled="disableInput(k)"
               class="form-control rowValue"
               id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
               ng-model="rowData[k]"/>

        <input ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k !== 'status' && k !== 'priority' && k !== 'severity' "
               ng-disabled="disableInput(k)"
               class="form-control rowValue"
               id="rowValue[{{$index}}]"
               ng-model="rowData[k].name"/>

        <select ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'status'"
                ng-model="k.statusId"
                class="form-control rowValue"
                id="statusId"
                ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventService.statusOptions()' >
            <option value=''>{{rowData[k].name}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'priority'"
                ng-model="k.priorityId"
                class="form-control rowValue"
                id="priorityId"
                ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventService.priorityOptions()' >
            <option value=''>{{rowData[k].name}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-if="isObject(rowData[k]) && k == 'severity'"
                ng-model="k.severityId"
                class="form-control rowValue"
                id="severityId"
                ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventService.severityOptions()' >
            <option value=''>{{rowData[k].name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow what you are doing.  Why do you have both rowKeys and rowData?  What doesn't rowData do for you that rowKeys does being that rowKeys appears to be just the keys from rowData?

Comment: @jbrown so rowKeys has been created with only one purpose to get keys of rowData, the value for this keys comes from rowData

Comment: I forked your plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xQpiZYwocRTSv1G1Ctzr?p=preview  I know its not the complete solution but I stripped out some things (ng-diabled, ng-if, ...) to try and get down to what I think you're trying to accomplish.  Let me know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: @jbrown you are definitely on the right way but Just noticed, I need to display keys..

Comment: I updated the plunker to show the key

Comment: @jbrown sorry but it can't be done like this `<div>Id: {{row.id}}</div>`. The thing is the data always comes different, in this example I have 'id', in next time I don't have it, but instead of this have 'itemId,' that's why I used ng-repeat that to build form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114773/discussion-between-jbrown-and-anton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 2 hours battle together with **@jbrown** we bet that. Change ng-repeat on ng-repeat=(key,value) and clear code for ng-model. So working code look like:

```
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in rowData">
          <div ng-if="(key === 'id' || key.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">
          <label for="value" class="col-sm-2">{{key}}</label>
           <div class=" col-sm-2">
           <input class="form-control rowValue"
           ng-if="!isObject(rowData[key])"
          type="text" ng-model="value"/>
       <input
       class="form-control rowValue"
       ng-if="isObject(value) && key !== 'status' && key !== 'priority' && key !== 'severity'"
           type="text" ng-model="value.name"/>

    <select ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'status'"
    ng-model="statusId"
    class="form-control rowValue"
    id="statusId"
    ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventService.statusOptions()' >
      <option value=''>{{value.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <select ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'priority'"
      ng-model="priorityId"
      class="form-control rowValue"
      id="priorityId"
      ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventService.priorityOptions()' >
        <option value=''>{{value.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'severity'"
        ng-model="severityId"
        class="form-control rowValue"
        id="severityId"
        ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventService.priorityOptions()' >
          <option value=''>{{value.name}}</option>
          </select>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

the rest of code doesn't need to change. [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3aGMj5CN4S4fZNRJja5y?p=preview)